# Chi squared test: which is the correct null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

I'm reviewing some literature in my field, specifically looking at whether physical activity (PA) has any beneficial effects on cognitive performance. The results across the studies are quite mixed. Lets say in my sample of 12 studies I see: 7 studies show a beneficial effect, 4 studies show no effect (non-significant), an 1 study shows a detrimental effect

I'm interested in statistically determining whether physical activity actually has a beneficial effect or not. I figure I can use a chi square test to see if the proportions are different from expected.

**What is the null hypothesis?**

I have 3 possible null hypotheses/distributions and I'm not sure which is correct for my formulation of the problem:

1. I could expect an equal probability of 1/3 for each category. The assumption being that if PA doesnt actually influence cognition, then the literature should be expected to show some benefits, some null results, and some detriments
2. Alternatively, if PA has no effect, then maybe the expected proportions are more like: benefits - 0, no effect - 1, detriment - 0. Because if PA doesnt affect cognitive performance at all then wouldn't we expect all studies to show non-significant findings?
3. I have a small sample size and one of the categories (detriment) only has 1 observation. Given that I'm interested in whether PA is actually beneficial, I could also combine the no effect and detrimental effect categories giving me 7 benefits and 5 non-benefits. Then test this against a null where the expected probabilities are .50 for each category. While this may make statistical sense due to the low # of observations, Im not sure if its theoretically correct

Which is the correct way to think about this problem? Or is a chi squared test completely inappropriate for this?

Comment: You seem to be in a meta-analytic setting - you are looking at a number of studies, each of which should report an effect size using the same metric.  Under certain conditions, you could pool effect size information across all studies to find out the magnitude of the overall effect.  Note that a non-significant p-value does not imply no effect - it merely implies no evidence of an effect. (Absence of evidence in favour of an effect does not constitute evidence of absence of the effect.)

Comment: My understanding is that a meta analysis will give me an overall effect size across the literature. For the purposes of this review the actual effect size isnt a huge concern, I'm more interested in determining the likelihood of finding a beneficial effect. Im not sure that an overall effect size means much if there is such a disparity in the literature? Either way, this review is more narrative in nature so the stats will always be supplementary/secondary - I'm just trying to figure out the correct way to do it

Comment: The problem is that you can't assume that a non-significant p-value means "no effect" - it only means no evidence of an effect. Also, whether or not a study found evidence of an effect depends on many factors, including study design, sample size, statistical analysis, etc. So it's hard to predict what will come out from each study unless you keep track of all the factors that can potentially influence its outcome.

Comment: @Simon I see no justification for possibility 1. You could argue that (if you used two tailed tests on a situation where there was no effect either way) that the proportion of showing benefit vs detriment should be equal but I see no reason to think the "not rejected" category should be 1/3; how did you figure that to be the case? Similarly possibility 2 makes no sense to me, given that the studies will have chosen a type I error rate above 0. Point 3 seems to inherit reasoning errors from its predecessors.

Comment: In meta-analysis, there are methods to combine p-values that result from tests of the same hypothesis. (Ex. [Fisher's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method)). But I suspect this approach won't be useful here: 1) Because the results include both beneficial and detrimental effects, the hypothesis tests were probably not formulated as one-sided tests in the same direction (h/t @gung); 2) I would guess that the some of the original studies used different tests (e.g. correlation or Mann Whitney) and so aren't technically testing the same hypothesis; and (cont...)

Comment: (... cont.) 3) There is likely meaningful heterogeneity in the conditions of the studies. Very possibility that is why there are decidedly mixed results. ... In these cases often the best one can do is summarize the results of the studies, perhaps with some emphasis on the different conditions among them, and not draw a hard conclusion, except to say, "This is why we need to study this more", and sometimes "Please fund me to do so."